# jQuery addClass with twitter bootstrap text field

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, addclass

A friend and I are building a jQuery Form Creator/Validator plugin, and we are also using twitter bootstrap because of its beautiful css elements!

**When the user click on the submit button we want to apply a class (that makes the input box-shadow red) to the form elements that are required.**

This works for all form elements except text. Apparently twitter bootstrap css is conflicting with the class in some way. The class is added to the element but nothing happens.

If someone out there could give us a hint, we would appreciate it!

Here is the code we are building (this is a simple version, of course):
http://jsfiddle.net/rdenadai/Hr9Gj/5/

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap's CSS rules are taking precedence over yours, since they are more specific, in particular, the [`input[type="text"]`](http://jsfiddle.net/hTjzh/1/) rule. To override them, add the `!important` declaration to your styles:

```
.required {
    border:1px solid rgba(196, 39, 39, 0.3) !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgba(196, 39, 39, 0.3) !important;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgba(196, 39, 39, 0.3) !important;
}
​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hTjzh/)**

Comment: Dude! Great, i never would think of that (or perhaps in some time i will)!

Comment: @rdenadai: Twitter Bootstrap can be tricky sometimes :). Feel free to mark my answer as accepted then http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work Thanks.,

Comment: My pleasure! Your answer sure did the job... i'm kind new on bootstrap but is a great tool!

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS isn't targeting the input field specifically enough, causing Bootstrap to override it. Try this:

```
input[type="text"].required {
    border:1px solid rgba(196, 39, 39, 0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgba(196, 39, 39, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgba(196, 39, 39, 0.3);
}
```

Comment: Joao answer solved my problem! Thanks for furter feedback guys... this thread can be closed!